# Help needed in creating a SQL statement containing four joins

Tags: sql-server, join

Please help. Given a studentID and a TagNumber i want to get the UserID related to that TagNumber. The difficult condition is that TagNumbers can be duplicate within a Users table. So we can pinpoint the exact UserID using the UserCities table as a student is linked to a school and a school is linked to a city and UserCities table have linking information for users and cities. You can assume that the given studentID:45 and TagNumber:99.

### Users:

UserID, TagNumber

### Students:

StudentID, SchoolID

### Schools:

SchoolID, CityID

### UserCities:

UserID, CityID

I have tried this so far:

```
select 
    u.UserID
  from
    UserCities uc  inner join School sc on uc.CityID = sc.CityID
    inner join Student st on sc.SchoolID = st.SchoolID
  where
    st.StudentID = 9
```

Comment: What SQL have you tried so far?

Comment: Question updated. I am always confused how to beautifully format my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it myself.

```
select 
    userID 
from 
    UserCities
where 
    CityID IN (select CityID 
               from school sc, student st 
               where sc.SchoolID = st.SchoolID and StudentID = 382) 
    and userID IN (select userID 
                   from users 
                   where tagNumber = 4521) ;
```

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ how could i have formatted the SQL text myself, like you did ?

Comment: click on the "edit" button and see for yourself! There is a "code sample" button that you can use to format code as code, i.e. padded with 4 spaces in the start of every line. See also [help/formatting](http://dba.stackexchange.com//help/formatting)